# Fetch error when convert base64 to blob on react-native

Tags: react-native, base64, blob

This error occurs when I run the following code in React Native to convert base64 to blob on Android

```
let url = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...';
let res = await fetch(url);
let blob = await res?.blob();
```

[image]

Comment: Could you solve the problem?

Comment: i am also facing same issue please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `Base64` to `blob` you can use the following way :

Install the package below

```
npm install buffer --save
```

First, convert your `Base64` to the array of bytes

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer";


const base64 = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEU ....'
let your_bytes = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
```

Then convert it to blob:

```
const blob = new Blob([your_bytes], { type: 'YOUR TYPE' })
```

Answer (score 0):

which `react-native-version` are you using ?

```js
const url = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA...';

const getBlob = async (uri) => {
  const res = await fetch(uri);
  return res.blob();
};

const blob = await getBlob(url);
```

Should work

Comment: version react-native 0.64.2

Comment: I tried the codes and it gave an error again

Comment: Only possibility that I can see why its not working is because of some faulty in the base64 data stream. By any chance did you decode this ?

Comment: Why does It work in IOS? but does not work in Android

Comment: Because of `JavascriptCore` differences between iOS & android. Read over here https://reactnative.dev/docs/javascript-environment

Comment: @Heisenberg have you find any solution?

Comment: @PasinduDilshan hav you find any solution